# Append the XML/HTML tag only if it's outside of a particular tag. JAVA/JSOUP

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

There are two cases:

1. If `<if>` tag is present outside of `<except>` tag then append `<print>` tag and also append `</print>` tag with respective `</if>` tag.
2. If `<print>` tag is already associated with `<if>` tag then no need to add it again.

The input XML is:

```
<if>
  <except>
    <if>
      <except>
        <if />
      </except>
    </if>
  </except>
</if>
```

And the expected output should be:

```
<if>
  <print>
    <except>
      <if>
        <except>
          <if />
        </except>
      </if>
    </except>
  </print>
</if>
```

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to consider `except` only as a direct parent of any of the parents?

Comment: I improved the formatting of the HTML code and added a final question. Still, the final question should be refined further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation in comments:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class StackOverflow58484337 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<if><except><if><except><if /></except></if></except></if>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
        // select every "if" element
        Elements ifs = doc.select("if");
        System.out.println("--- before:");
        System.out.println(doc);
        // check every "if" element if any of its parents is "except" element
        for (Element singleIf : ifs) {
            if (isOutsideExcept(singleIf)) {
                // wrap it in "print" element
                singleIf.children().wrap("<print>");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("--- after:");
        System.out.println(doc);
    }

    private static boolean isOutsideExcept(Element singleIf) {
        Element parent = singleIf.parent();
        // check parent, and parent of his parent, and parent of his parent ...
        while (parent != null) {
            if (parent.tagName().equals("except")) {
                return false;
            }
            parent = parent.parent();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

output:

```
--- before:
<if>
 <except>
  <if>
   <except>
    <if />
   </except>
  </if>
 </except>
</if>
--- after:
<if>
 <print>
  <except>
   <if>
    <except>
     <if />
    </except>
   </if>
  </except>
 </print>
</if>
```

Comment: Thanks!, its working as intended. And for Case-2 I just added one condition inside for loop, now its works fine.

Comment: If you like the answer remember to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: For the provided case its failing :input: `<IF><A></A><P></P><Q><S></S><A></A></Q></IF>`
output:`<IF><PRINT><A></A></PRINT><PRINT><P></P></PRINT><PRINT><Q><S></S><A></A></Q></PRINT></IF>`
expected output: `<IF><PRINT><A></A><P></P><Q><S></S><A></A></Q></PRINT></IF>`. How can I resolve this one.

Comment: Lowercase `if` is different than uppercase `IF`. That's probably why select doesn't find it.

Comment: In select I given uppercase `IF` only, in that case as well I am getting the output as mentioned above.